# Stored in stack or heap

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

Question regarding stack and heap in java

When a static variable, method or class is created in java - where is it stored? Is it stored on the call stack or on the heap?

I mean:

static (inner) classes

static fields

static methods

Answer (score 3):

All non-local things not explicitly stored off-heap are stored on the heap. This includes class definitions, fields, and static fields.

Only local variables (in the scope of a single method, constructor, etc) are on the call stack.

Beyond there this is nastily-implementation-dependent. (Hotspot native code storage, anyone?)